# Print lines matching a pattern only if the next line does not match the pattern

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to print lines that match a pattern only if the following line does not match the pattern. In this case, the pattern is that the line begins with **O**. This is what I tried:

```
awk '!/^O/ {print x}; /^O/ {x=$0}' myfile.txt
```

This is printing far too many lines though, including printing the lines I specifically do not want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested.
Should probz work

```
awk '/^O/{if(seen==0){seen=1};c=$0} !/^O/{if (seen==1) {print c; seen=0;}}' myfile.txt
```

Shortened version

```
 awk '/^O/{x=$0} !/^O/{if(x!=0) {print x; x=0;}}' myfile.txt
```

More shortening

```
awk '/^O/{x=$0} !/^O/{if(x){print x;x=0;}}' myfile
```

Think this is shortest it can go

```
awk '/^O/{x=$0} !/^O/&&x{print x;x=0;}' myfile
```

Changed them all because it printed the wrong lines.

also made it shorter :)

```
awk 'a=/^O/{x=$0} !a&&x{print x;x=0;}' myfile
```

Comment: The updated queries do indeed solve exactly the problem I posed. It turns out however that the problem I face is somewhat different than I had originally thought. Here is the updated question:

For each group of consecutive lines matching a pattern, print only the first one. If there is a group of 2 or 3 or more consecutive lines beginning with O, print only the first one of these lines.

Once a line not matching the pattern is encountered, this should reset the state. Among the next group of consecutive O lines, just the first one should be printed, and so on.

Comment: Oh, and in case this was not clear: if a solitary O line is encountered, print it.

So, in summary:
For each group of 1 or more consecutive lines matching a pattern, print the first one of the group.

Comment: This seems to do the trick:
`awk '/^O/{if(seen==0){seen=1;print $0}} !/^O/{if (seen==1) {seen=0}}'`

Comment: Yep all the first set of answers should work for that :) Just look at before the last edit