# How to not print a line if it and the following line starts with the same pattern?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file.fa:

```
>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>BDC
>DTR
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

I want to keep the lines without ">", and lines with ">" only if the immediate following line does not have ">":

```
>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

Looking at the answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427012/print-lines-matching-a-pattern-only-if-the-next-line-does-not-match-the-pattern), I see that `awk '/^>/{x=$0} !/^>/{if(x){print x;x=0;}}' file.fa` prints out the header lines (with '>') that I want:

```
>ABC
>EDF
```

but how do I also get the lines of text without '>'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```sh
$  sed '/^>/ { N; /\n>/ D; }' input.txt
>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

If a line starts with `>`, read the next line and append it to the pattern space. If it also starts with `>`, delete the first line of the pattern space and repeat with the second line just read as the new input line to look at. Print everything else.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the breakdown and simplicity of this answer

Answer (score 6):

You may use:

```sh
awk '!/^>/ {if (prev != "") print prev; print; prev=""}
/^>/ {prev = $0}' file

>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '!/>/{print p $0; p=""; next} {p=$0 ORS}' file
>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

The above assumes you don't have a `>` line as the last line of the input.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) as `>` and field separator as new line. If NF is greater than `2` then print that line with `>` and it values.

```
awk -v RS='>' -v FS='\n' 'NF>2{sub(/\n$/,"");print ">" $0}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

We always have perl:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 while(/^(>.*\R^[^>][\s\S]*?)(?=^>|\z)/gm)' file
>ABC
TGTGTGT
AGAGAGA
TGTAGTA
>EDF
AGAGGTG
AGTGACA
CAGTGAC
```

In awk you could do:

```
awk -F"^>" 'NF>1{p=$0 ORS; next}
{printf "%s%s", p, $0 ORS; p=""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^>.*\n>/!P;D' file
```